# Disable date based archives for all categories except one

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, archives

I want to remove all date base archive url permalinks (url_rewrites) from my site, excluding for only 1 category. How can i do that.

For example:

- `www.example.com/category_1/2012/`     ->  404 error
- `www.example.com/category_2/2012/`     ->  404 error

but:

- `www.example.com/category_3/2012/`     ->  show category_3 posts from year 2012.

How can I do that?